# MOSFET resistor, difference with no gate or gate at 0V

Tags: voltage, transistors, mosfet, resistivity

While measuring a MOSFET resistivity without a gate voltage I have observed that the resistivity obtained for a gate voltage at 0V is 20 times higher than the resistivity observed when there is no gate at all (with classical 4 probes measurement on a material).
Does someone have an explanation for this phenomena?
Thanks a lot

Comment: You're going to have to provide a diagram and type of MOSFET. Resistivity of what? The channel?

Comment: The gate of a MOSFET will **always** have a certain voltage, even when you do not connect it. If you do not connect it, you will not know what the voltage is so it can be **anything** because a charge can be trapped on the gate. So **ALWAYS connect the gate**

Answer (score 5):

The gate is insulated from the rest of the MOSFET therefore it can accumulate charge and start to turn on the device. This pretty much makes testing a MOSFET with no electrical connection to the gate a waste of time.